# Create serial count in column if adjacent cell is blank (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, is-empty

I'm trying to create a simple counting ArrayFormula that iterates by one, if adjacent cell is empty (doesn't contain "IGNORE"). E.g. `COUNT` column here should only count when `STATUS` <> `IGNORE`:

```
ROW   STATUS    COUNT
______________________
1     IGNORE    
2     IGNORE
3                 1
4                 2
5                 3
6     IGNORE
7     IGNORE
8                 4
9                 5
```

What ArrayFormula can I use here in cell C1 `COUNT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function and integrate it with `ARRAYFORMULA`.

### Example

**Code:**

```
function countNonIgnore(values) {
  var tempArr = [];
  var ctr = 1;
  values.forEach(val => {
    if(val[0] == "IGNORE"){
      tempArr.push([""]);
    }else{
      tempArr.push([ctr]);
      ctr++;
    }
  })
  return tempArr;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: This is amazing, and works like a charm. My introduction to custom functions. Thanks indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Option using standard functions:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B10<>"IGNORE",COUNTIFS(B2:B10<>"IGNORE",B2:B10<>"IGNORE",ROW(B2:B10),"<="&ROW(B2:B10)),))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a formula in `C1`, I would use something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(B:B)=1, "COUNT", IF((B:B<>"IGNORE")*(A:A<>""), COUNTIFS(B:B<>"IGNORE", TRUE, ROW(B:B), "<="&ROW(B:B))-1,)))
```

[image]

If in `C2`, then

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B2:B<>"IGNORE")*(A2:A<>""), COUNTIFS(B2:B<>"IGNORE", TRUE, ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B)),))
```